# What percentage/ratio of entry nodes reside in 14 Eyes or NATO affiliated countries?

Tags: configuration, guard-node, traffic-analysis

I spent a good amount of time editing my Tor configuration files to switch in between entry nodes and found that eventually after excluding all nodes, I was lastly routed through Kyrgyzstan. I only noticed a couple entry nodes that resided outside the 14Eyes/NATO, which led me to ask this question. It appears that most of the Tor nodes in general are in Europe and the US, however, I wonder if this will change in the future, where we might see more Asian, African, and South American countries getting their own entry nodes.

Some part of me thinks this is all one large traffic correlation network lol that is just speculation at this point but I think it is kind of weird that we don't see more entry nodes in obscure countries.

Comment: You can find the geographical distribution of relays here: https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#aggregate/cc

Answer (score 0):

27 NATO countries have guard nodes (only 3 don't have). Combining the guard probability for each NATO country gives a 89.3939% likely to get a guard in a NATO country.

New Zealand has only 1 guard so the likelihood of getting a guard hosted there is less than 0.0000%. Otherwise you are 18.6385% likely to get a Four eyes guard. You are 43.8656% likely to get an Eight eyes guard. You are 81.3584% likely to get a 13 eyes guard.

2963 guard nodes are hosted in NATO countries. Out of ~3600. That means 82.3056% of guard nodes are hosted in NATO countries.

992 guard nodes are hosted in five eyes countries (27.5556%). 1671 guard nodes are hosted in nine eyes countries (46.4167%). 2694 guard nodes are hosted in 14 eyes countries (74.8333%).

You can see more on the [relay search website](https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html), the specific query and settings I used was this: https://metrics.torproject.org/rs.html#aggregate/cc/flag:guard%20